# Работа с большими объемами

Tags: диск, проверка

Всем привет, есть вопрос: возможно ли в linux проверить хард объемом около терабайта? П.С. проберить полностью - поверхность, беты и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки дисков, на бэд-блоки и ошибки файловой системы достаточно утилит [e2fsprogs](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/E2fsprogs). Можно поступить так: проверять файловые системы `fsck`, а искать бэд-блоки `badblock`. Описания обоих команд через `man`. Если диск терабайтный, то нужно учесть, что проверка будет идти долго, и потребуется достаточно памяти (на терабайт порядка гигабайта), иначе начнет свопится и будет совсем медленно.